# How to add total average with a filter condition in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a couple of tables with different categories (Month, Product, Year, etc.), each has 2 measures AVG Time and Volume and I'm trying to add a total average column at the end of each table.

This is what I get now:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to get:

[image]

It would be a very straightforward solution but my data has some values that I'm excluding and I think this messes up with my formula:

```
AVG =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( Data[Time] ),
    FILTER (
        Data,
        AND (
            [Time] <> 9999999,
            [Time] >= 0
        )
    ),
    ALL ( Data )
)
```

Tried ALLSELECTED, ALLEXCEPT but they also didn't help.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your formula, except that you could simplify the calculate modifier. What is the formula supposed to do?

Comment: added another screenshot, it suppose to have the total average numbers in the last column and it doesn't do it

Comment: Then put the ALL( Data ) inside the FILTER().

Comment: Could you show where exactly it should go? Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it: CALCULATE (AVERAGE ( Data[Time] ), FILTER (ALL(Data),.....

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
AVG =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( Data[Time] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL(Data),
        AND (
            [Time] <> 9999999,
            [Time] >= 0
        )
    ),
    ALL ( Data )
)
```